# Sql query to Clear existing email addresses from table

Tags: sql-server-2008

Sql query to Clear existing email addresses from table.

please I need help

Comment: Please see [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977). Based on your minimal effort, all we could assume is  `update table set emailAddresses = null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see at least 2 variants .. but you give very little information - even your goal is not obvious.

1) remove email-column

```
ALTER TABLE "table_name" DROP "column_name";
```

2) delete email-addresses [ with restriction to a specific address

```
UPDATE "table_name" SET email_address=null [ WHERE email_address='jane.doe@example.com']
```

Comment: thank for the reply.there are 4 different email address fields Email_fax, Email_num, Email2, email_add3. so for all of them i have to do same queries ? there are numbers of different email addresses and all of them need to be clear.

Comment: you can include those in the update statement .. it allows changing of more than one column ... but needs some work in the where part as well 
>where column1=x or column2=x or column3=x 
... in that pattern